# Trying to find a "backdoor" to the number of shares/+1's/stumbles a website has

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I need to access the number of facebook shares, google +1's, stumbles for a given website.  My first thought was to use `file_get_contents` on the url of the button alone, removing everything but the number but in hindsight, the number is gotten using javascript so I sanitized out the html and left the javascript.  I've managed to find a url for twitter:

```
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=[put encoded url here]
```

This returns a json object as follows:

```
{"count":52,"url":"[url here"}
```

I have gone over the code for the buttons for hours using firebug but I'm not that great at Javascript so sometimes I'm not even sure what I'm looking at.  Anybody have any ideas at how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For facebook you can use the opengraph.

Example https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

You can then extract all the info from the json object.

Comment: I had thought about that.  My problem is that what I'm tracking is the number of times an article is shared from a website so I'm not sure how to pull up the graph of the individual article without the id or how to get the id from the url of the article.

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=YOUR_URL

Replace 'YOUR_URL' with the url of the article.
If the article has been shared, it should show

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much.  I think I can use Google Analytics as a datasource for with CakePHP but any ideas for Stumbleupon?  btw I tried to vote up the answer but I'm new and apparently my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: Nevermind.  Found it.  In case anybody else needs it: http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=[YOUR URL]